# I am trying to use array as database

Tags: javascript, php, session

I am working on a small application in which I need to use array as database. I have a form containing name and age field in php file named **index.php**. My **Index.php** looks like this:

```
<pre><code>
<?php 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['var'] = 0;
?>

<html>    
<body>
<form action="weloome.php" method="post">
    Name : <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
    Age  : <input type="text" name="age"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit=
    "<?php $_SESSION['var'] += 1; ?>/>">  
</form>
</body>
</html>
</code>
```

In this code I Use session variable var which gets increment on the onsubmit event of form. It gets increment because I want all values to be stored in array called db_array().

This is second file **welcome.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $db_array[$_SESSION['var']][0] = $_POST['name'];
    $db_array[$_SESSION['var']][1] = $_POST['age'];
    print_r($db_array);
?>
<a href="index.php">Want to Add more Record? Click Here</a>
```

But the problem is that `$_SESSION['var'] = 0;` initializes with zero every time
when user click on link on above page. That is why only last record is shown because array is overwritten. Any Solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Verify IF your $_SESSION already has a value, if YES, don't `$_SESSION['var'] = 0;` again

Answer (score 1):

Add a conditional:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["var"]) {
    $_SESSION["var"] = 0;
}
```

This will only initialize the session only if it hasn't been initialized before.

Comment: We encountered a race condition :) and came up with the exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

is weloome the correct name? is that a typo?

Comment: nice... ;-) ha ha ha +1 for that mate

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: If your variable is empty, it will initialize it with zero, else it will remain the same ;-)

```
<?php 
if(!$_SESSION['var'])
    $_SESSION['var'] = 0;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this check,

```
if(session_id()=="")
{
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['var']=0;
}
```

this will only execute if session is not found.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP versions 5.4* and later, this is the most efficient way to see if session is already started or not.

```
if(session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
{
  // session is not started yet
  session_start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to develop this further, you could use the serialize functions to convert it into something you can store, in a cookie perhaps, or a file, or a database..

the serialize function converts the array into a string that can be stored. Sort of looks like json.

If you got any more questions, is there a way to notify me? can i follow people like on facebook/twitter?